# Convert array inside JSON into object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following data which is coming from a **GraphQL endpoint**:

```
{
  "data": {
    "metatags": [
      {
        "title": "Metatag title",
        "description": "Metatag description"
      }
    ],
    "herounits": [
      {
        "title": "Hero unit title",
        "description": "Hero unit description"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to replace the arrays inside of it into JSON objects as the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "metatags": {
      {
        "title": "Metatag title",
        "description": "Metatag description"
      }
    },
    "herounits": {
      {
        "title": "Hero unit title",
        "description": "Hero unit description"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Been trying different approaches but none been working yet.

Comment: Your expected result is not valid; you can't nest an object directly inside of an object like that. What are you actually trying to achieve? What's the problem with the array you have now?

Comment: You need a key inside an object - only your first one is valid.

Comment: Hi @Pointy, thanks for the reply! I'm using a plugin called Vuex-i18n which doesn't allows accessing as herounits[0].title, so I need to get the final result without arrays, the GraphQL endpoint is coming from Strapi headless CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desire object is not valid, you have an extra level of object nesting without property names.

Assuming what you actually want is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "metatags": {
        "title": "Metatag title",
        "description": "Metatag description"
    },
    "herounits": {
        "title": "Hero unit title",
        "description": "Hero unit description"
    }
  }
}
```

you can do it by replacing each property with the value in element `0` of the array.

```js
let obj = {
  "data": {
    "metatags": [
      {
        "title": "Metatag title",
        "description": "Metatag description"
      }
    ],
    "herounits": [
      {
        "title": "Hero unit title",
        "description": "Hero unit description"
      }
    ]
  }
};

Object.keys(obj.data).forEach(k => obj.data[k] = obj.data[k][0]);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, that's exactly what I needed, it's working great, thank you so muuuuch!!! :D